# Is it possible to specify two different type param values for parent and child components in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Please refer the following code blocks. For that code blocks, I have tried to access the parent component values into child component, but it always return the null value in child component.

`Component.razor`:

```
<Parent TValue="TreeData">
 <Child TValue="TreeNode<TreeData>"></Child>
</Parent>

@code {
    public class TreeData
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class TreeNode<TreeData>
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Parent.razor`:

```
<CascadingValue Value="@this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

`Child.razor`:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Parent<TValue> ParentObj { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        //Parent obj always returns the null value
        ParentObj?.UpdateChildProperties("UpdateData", this);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to piece together your code and create a working example.  Can you restructure the code into the parent and child components?

Comment: why you create a generic class with specified class type? you have to use public parameter for cascade parameter.

Comment: Your code is missing the `@typeparam TValue` which I assume must be in Parent and Child

Answer (score 1):

Some general things to consider:

1. Make sure your child component (or your _Imports.razor) has a using statement for that namespace.
2. The [CascadingParameter] in the child must be public.
3. Make the type of the [CascadingParameter] the name of the parent (without the.razor)
4. If you have multiple different types you want to pass as a cascading parameter that's fine, just make another [CascadingParameter] in the child.
5. If they need to use the same [CascadingParameter] in the child component then all those types that are being passed down must inherit from the same class (.razor). This .razor can be empty just make sure to include @inherits (whatever your base type is) and make the type of the [CascadingParameter] in the child the type of the base and in the on initialize you can check for type and cast it if needed.

I believe doing these things should fix this issue but as Curtis mentioned in the comment - it is difficult to follow this code with the way it is separated.

Answer (score 0):

In `Parent.razor` you cascade `@this`, which is of type `Parent<TreeData>`.

In `Child.razor` you catch the cascading value as a cascading parameter of type `Parent<TValue>`. As per passed `TValue` = `TreeNode<TreeData>` it translates to `Parent<TreeNode<TreeData>>`.

The cascading value and cascading parameter have mismatching types (`Parent<TreeData>` vs `Parent<TreeNode<TreeData>>`). That is why the cascading parameter is always null.